# How to change the color of dragging tool (or) resizing tool in angular ui-grid?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ui-grid

To add the feature of resizing of the columns in my angular application I used `ui.grid.resizeColumns`.The problem is the dragging option tool being used in the API is black in color which is not visible on the background color of my grid.

Which CSS needs to be changed to change the color of the resizing tool which appears while trying to resize a column ?

The HTML Mark up is as below.

```
<div id="scrolltemplate" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid-25" ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
```

which css contains styles related to the resizing tool icon or image that is used for dragging the colums ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ui-grid-column-resizer {
  cursor: url('path-to-cursor-image.png'), auto;    
}
```

Comment: Though i didnt use the above one, I just changed the cursor to e-resize. `cursor: e-resize` Thanks for pointing out the correct class file to check for